Proving an Identity on Partitions with Durfee Squares Using $q$-Binomial Coefficients and Generating Functions

Using the Durfee square, prove that
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n\left[\begin{array}{l}
n \\
j
\end{array}\right] \frac{t^j q^{j^2}}{(1-t q) \cdots\left(1-t q^j\right)}=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1-t q^i} .
$$

My thoughts:
Structure of the Partition
Each partition $\pi$ with a Durfee square of side $j$ decomposes as:
(a) the Durfee square;
(b) a partition $\pi_1$ that fits into a $j \times (n-j)$ box; and
(c) a partition $\pi_2$ that fits into a $j \times j$ box to the right of $\pi_1$.
Sum of the Parts of $\pi$
If $|\pi|$ represents the sum of the parts of $\pi$, then:
$$
|\pi|=j^2 + |\pi_1| + |\pi_2|
$$
Generating Function Interpretation

Durfee Square Contribution: The Durfee square itself contributes $q^{j^2}$, accounting for each square within the Durfee square.
Generating $\pi_1$:

$\pi_1$ consists of parts above the Durfee square. This can have at most $j$ parts, each of size at most $n-j$. The generating function for these partitions is represented by $\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ j \end{array}\right]$.


Generating $\pi_2$:

$\pi_2$ consists of parts to the right of the Durfee square, involving parts that decrease in size from $j$ to $1$. The generating function for these parts, accommodating the gradation and inclusion of the parameter $t$ for counting purposes, is $\frac{t^j}{(1-tq)(1-tq^2) \cdots (1-tq^j)}$.



Combining Contributions
Putting it all together, the generating series for such partitions $\pi$ becomes:
$$
q^{j^2}\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ j \end{array}\right] \frac{t^j}{(1-tq)(1-tq^2) \cdots (1-tq^j)}
$$
Summing Over All Durfee Squares
To cover all possible configurations of partitions up to a maximum part size of $n$:
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n q^{j^2}\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ j \end{array}\right] \frac{t^j}{(1-tq)(1-tq^2) \cdots (1-tq^j)} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1-t q^i},
$$
where the right-hand side directly generates all partitions with parts not exceeding $n$, each part contributing a factor of $t$ and $q^i$ to the partition's weight. This accounts for all possible partitions (with and without structural constraints like Durfee squares) fitting into a Ferrers diagram up to size $n$.

So... What's the question? It seems that you already have a supposed proof? Do you ask to review it?

Also, what exactly is $\left[ \begin{matrix}n \ j\end{matrix}\right]$ here? It's usually used to denote Stirling numbers of the first kind, but unlikely to match from the context. Did you mean $\binom{n}{j}_q$?
